# Python speech_recognition not detecting audio from microphone

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, microphone

I'm currently looking into building my own home automation system controllable through voice commands. I've learned about the package SpeechRecognition and decided this would be how I interact with my system.

After reading tutorials, and the reference pages from github, and also looking at sample scripts I have come up with the following code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

r=sr.Recognizer()

    #Microphone(device_index=i, sample_rate=48000)
with sr.Microphone( sample_rate=48000) as source:
    print("Say Something!")
    audio=r.listen(source)

with open("microphone-results.wav", "wb") as f:
    f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
```

When testing my code it runs and displays "Say Something!" however no matter what I say into my microphone, or how long the code runs for nothing happens and no "microphone-results.wav" file is created.

I know my microphone works because I can test it with the command **arecord -D plughw:1,0 test.wav** and play back the file using **aplay test.wav**

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest update of Rasbian.

Comment: You need to reconfigure alsa so that pulghw:1,0 will be your default device. Or you need to point the device index. Otherwise it records only silence and never returns.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem!
If you would like to post that as an answer to the question I would be happy to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

i also had same problem but i finally came to the solution here is the    lines of code for detecting only one frequency sound
after the [print("Say something") just paste

```
r.pause_threshold=1
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1) 

then you will get the message whatever you speak after 5 to 10 seconds
```